# What went wrong with my Kruskal-Wallis class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, kruskal-wallis

I was trying to build a class that could perform the Kruskal-Wallis test. The class uses the following formula to compute H:

[image: formula to compute H]

However, it yields a different H-value than the `kruskal` function of scipy. Does anyone know why this is the case?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import rankdata
from scipy.stats import kruskal

class Kruskal_Wallis():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fit(self, groups):
        """
        Performs Kruskal-Wallis test.

        :param groups: list containing 1D group arrays

        Adds the following attributes:
            - n: size of total population
            - n_groups: number of groups (n_groups = len(n_i) = len(r_i))
            - n_i: array containing group sizes
            - df: degrees of freedom
            - r2_i: array containing the square of the sum of ranks for each group
            - h: kruskal-wallis statistic
        """

        def sum_ranks_per_group(groups):
            n_groups = len(groups)
            n_i = np.array([group.shape[0] for group in groups])

            data = np.array([])
            for group in groups:
                data = np.concatenate((data, group), axis=0)

            ranked_data = rankdata(data, method="average")
            ranked_groups = ranked_data.reshape((n_groups, n_i[0])) #works only if groups have equal size
            summed_ranks = ranked_groups.sum(axis=1)

            return summed_ranks

        def get_h(n, r2_i, n_i):
            summed_r2_i_per_n_i = (r2_i/n_i).sum()
            h = (12/(n*(n-1)) * summed_r2_i_per_n_i) - 3*(n+1)

            return h

        n_groups = len(groups)
        n_i = np.array([group.shape[0] for group in groups])
        n = sum(n_i)
        df = n_groups - 1
        r2_i = sum_ranks_per_group(groups)**2
        h = get_h(n, r2_i, n_i)

        self.n_groups = n_groups
        self.n_i = n_i
        self.n = n
        self.df = df
        self.r2_i = r2_i
        self.h = h


## Compare results yielded by  scipy.stats.kruskal and Kruskal_Wallis class
groups = [np.arange(1,3),
        np.arange(3,5)]

res = kruskal(groups[0], groups[1])

kruskal_wallis = Kruskal_Wallis()
kruskal_wallis.fit(groups)
print(res)
print(kruskal_wallis.h)
```

Answer (score 0):

the difference between the answers might be caused by the way python handles `float` type in the [division operations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Instead of using pythonic division (`/`) try using numpy's [true division](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I solved the problem. The formula given in my textbook had a typo. The correct formula to compute H is 12/(N*(N+1)) not 12/(N*(N-1))